# AWS CDK: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK and it is failing at App-Load-Balancer level and surprisingly it works for Web-Load-balancer. Looking at generated CloudFormation, it is clear that all "Private Subnets" are getting created in separated AZ and associated Auto-Scaling Group too is creating the instance across multiple-AZs. However, when the CDK is executed, it is failing with the error message - *A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Co
de: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: 62c554cb-34ab-43ef-bac0-be2f0d6fc742; Proxy: null)*

### APP Server characteristics

**AUTOSCALING CF Snippet:**

```
      "InstaLendaappASGapp1appsvrASG950CF7C4": {
    "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
    "Properties": {
      "MaxSize": "3",
      "MinSize": "1",
      "DesiredCapacity": "2",
      "LaunchConfigurationName": {
        "Ref": "InstaLendaappASGapp1appsvrLaunchConfig18DAF6BB"
      },
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "PropagateAtLaunch": true,
          "Value": "webapp-dc-3-tier-ha/InstaLend-a-appASG-app-1-appsvr-"
        }
      ],
      "TargetGroupARNs": [
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendaapplbInstaLendalstnrPrivate80InstaLendatgtprivateGroup8D2C8D01"
        }
      ],
      "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet1Subnet35AF6769"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet2SubnetD8513C5D"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet3SubnetB7B2D12C"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**LOADBALANCER CF Snippet:**

```
      "InstaLendaapplbCC4F6682": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
    "Properties": {
      "LoadBalancerAttributes": [
        {
          "Key": "deletion_protection.enabled",
          "Value": "false"
        }
      ],
      "Name": "InstaLend-a-app-lb",
      "Scheme": "internal",
      "SecurityGroups": [
        {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "InstaLendasginternal8649CE7C",
            "GroupId"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Subnets": [
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet1Subnet35AF6769"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet2SubnetD8513C5D"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet3SubnetB7B2D12C"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNDBSubnet1Subnet2DD722D8"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNDBSubnet2Subnet59278CD3"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNDBSubnet3SubnetCC805230"
        }
      ],
      "Type": "application"
    },
    "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Delete",
    "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
    "Metadata": {
      "aws:cdk:path": "webapp-dc-3-tier-ha/InstaLend-a-app-lb/Resource"
    }
  }
```

While LB is selecting 6 subnets, ASG associated is selecting only 3 subnets. The details of 3 ASG Subnets (i.e. Private Subnets) had been pasted below:

### 1st SUBNET

```
      "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet1Subnet35AF6769": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "CidrBlock": "10.2.3.0/24",
      "VpcId": {
        "Ref": "InstaLendavpcE5C8A638"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
          "Value": "InstaLend-a-privateSN"
      ....
```

### 2nd SUBNET

```
      "InstaLendavpcInstaLendaprivateSNSubnet2SubnetD8513C5D": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "CidrBlock": "10.2.4.0/24",
      "VpcId": {
        "Ref": "InstaLendavpcE5C8A638"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
          "Value": "InstaLend-a-privateSN"
        },
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
          "Value": "Private"
        },
      ....
```

### 3rd SUBNET

```
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "CidrBlock": "10.2.5.0/24",
      "VpcId": {
        "Ref": "InstaLendavpcE5C8A638"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2c",
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
          "Value": "InstaLend-a-privateSN"
        },
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
          "Value": "Private"
        },
```

Comment: Are the six subnets attached to the application load balancer (`AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`) all in different AZs? The subnets of the autoscaling group do not matter